# Any solution for browser based online voice/video chat?

Tags: javascript, flash

I need to setup a website which can help people to have 1 to N, 1 to 1 online voice chat , but not sure which way is the most quick way to implement it?  anyone has experience for this can give me some real world solutions for it? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are considering to use flash, you will need a RTMP streaming server> I suggest you to take a look into the 2 below:
Wowza Media Server 
http://www.wowza.com/

Red5 (Open Source)
http://www.red5.org/

There are examples into their websites on how to setup a basic video chat application.

Comment: you can also check this product: https://www.synergychat.com:8443/whitelabel-marketing

Comment: Any other ready-to-use service which can be integrated to my own website?  I don't expect to do much development here if possible

Comment: check the synergychat product then